# Making the webform submission results as a link in Drupal 6?

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-modules, drupal-webform

I am a newbie in using `Drupal 6` and I am still *walking in the dark* in terms of module familiarization and module configurations. Lately, I installed the `Webform` module for my site to be able to let users submit a request. In my `Webform`, there is a `Select View` field where it lists all contents of a specific `Content Type` on my `Drupal` site. I was able to use a `View` as a datasource for my normal webform select component via the `Webform View Reference Component` that's whay I have a custom `<select>` field which are views on my `Webform`. Now, after a successful submission of the form, I go to `Results` and found the data which are saved upon submission. What I want is that, on my `Results` page, the `selected` option from the list, which basically are views, will be a link to their respective views. This is how it looks like, [image]
I am really lost right here. Can someone lend me a hand on how to make this possible? Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Install this module http://drupal.org/project/webform_report it will be displayed in table format and also you can customize the report & also It will create separate content type.

Below is the screen shot for webform report, you can also view, edit & delete from report itself.

[image]